# Why does Adobe Reader have an internal error when copying text to clipboard?

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

This has been an intermittent but common problem for me. It's been raised on other forums (e.g. http://forums.adobe.com/message/5306610) but no clear answer has been provided, as far as I can tell. I've found that if I have many documents open in Adobe Reader closing one or two might then help me copy text. Then a few minutes later I will get the same error message.

[image]

Comment: This question is asking for explanation of a bug and only developers can answer it. 

Comment: I suggest you contact Adobe. You should be able to submit a trouble report from their website.